# VBA : Parse Hyperlink based on Column Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have below script to copy and do filter based on array. In range B:B i have Link that I want to parse into another range of column, let's say in column BM:BM but I'm not sure its can be incorporated to the first script

```
Function GetURL(Rng As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetURL = Rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

---

```
Sub AnotherTry2()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range
    Dim critSite As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim TempArray As Variant

    Set wbSite = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSite = wbSite.Worksheets("newlist")
    Set critSite = wsSite.ListObjects("Table6")

    TempArray = critSite.DataBodyRange
    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\Data.xlsx", , True)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Report 1")
    wsSource.Range("A:BL").AutoFilter field:=50, Criteria1:=myArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("raw")

    wsDest.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wsSource.Range("A1:BL200000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsDest.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    wbDest.Save 
    wbSource.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with "parse" a link?

Comment: sorry for confusion, I mean its excel hyperlink, e.g. written as [stack](http://stackoverflow.com)when you click it goes to stackoverflow.com . So what I want is to parsing that hyperlink to a string as a complete address but in another column

Comment: Ok. you're copying 200.000 cells from one file to the other (wbDest). question 1) Is in the wbDest workbook that you want to add the column? 2) Edit your question and show us how a couple of links are stored in the excel cells (look at the formula when you are over one cell)

Comment: 1, yes after filtered all data visible copied from wbsource to wbdest A:BL but its seems to be fine 2) range B:B that copied all is hyperlink I want to make it as complete address instead it in column BM:BM using function mentioned below, or if there's any other possible solution

Comment: 3) And show us how would you want them to be displayed? or simply make them clickable is what you mean.

Comment: b:b already hyperlink mean can be clicked e.g. column B1 [link no1](http://website1.com)  and column B2 [link no2](http://website2.com), so in BM1 i want to show as http://website1.com , BM2 shown http://website2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code:

```
wsDest.Range("BM1:BM200000").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(B1,B1)"
```

After this line:

```
wsDest.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

I suggest you to do a test with less rows before trying with the whole dataset.

Comment: thanks it works ! and also i tried to change with `wsDest.Range("BM2:BM200000").Formula = "=GetURL(B2)"` also works